# Getting window coordinates of the insertion point - Cocoa

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, coordinates

What is the best way to get window coordinates of the current caret position in a text edit control in Cocoa?

Here is how I do that in other platforms

1. Windows - `EM_POSFROMCHAR`
2. GTK - Using `gtk_text_view_get_iter_location` and `gtk_text_view_buffer_to_window_coords`.

I am wondering how the same can be done using Cocoa. I am on MacOSX 10.6.8 and I am doing this using C++.

Comment: I will be ineterested in NSTextView. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: One more question: you’ve tagged your question as c++ but Cocoa offers mainly an Objective-C API. Is Objective-C (or Objective-C++) a viable solution or are you interested in C++ only?

Comment: Any idea about how to approach the problem would be good enough. I can  work around the language issues. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `textView` is a variable that points to the text view and `window` is a variable that points to the window:

```
// -firstRectForCharacterRange:actualRange returns a frame rectangle
// containing the insertion point or, in case there's a selection,
// the first line of that selection. The origin of the frame rectangle is
// in screen coordinates
NSRange range = [textView selectedRange];
NSRect screenRect = [textView firstRectForCharacterRange:range actualRange:NULL];

// -convertRectFromScreen: converts from screen coordinates
// to window coordinates
NSRect windowRect = [window convertRectFromScreen:screenRect];

// The origin is the lower left corner of the frame rectangle
// containing the insertion point
NSPoint insertionPoint = windowRect.origin;
```

Comment: In C++? That doesn't look like any C++ I've seen.

Comment: @Dead See the comments section in the question.

Comment: BTW, what is the `window` variable? Instance of `NSWindow`? If yes, should I pass the window instance where `NSTextView` is shown? I am confused because this is slightly different in MS Windows and GTK. In both, each item like text field are actually instances of window/widget. So to convert screen coordinates to window coordinates, the window provided is the text field itself. But here NsTextView is not a window. So I am confused. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

The following method is in the documentation

`- (void)drawInsertionPointInRect:(NSRect)aRect color:(NSColor *)aColor turnedOn:(BOOL)flag`

it says

> The focus must be locked on the receiver when this method is invoked. You should not need to invoke this method directly.

If you override this method (and call the super implementation) in an NSTextView subclass it would allow you to know the position of the insertion point, at least when it's required by Cocoa.

Comment: In C++? That doesn't look like any C++ I've seen.

Comment: If you want to use Cocoa (which is a combination of the Foundation and AppKit frameworks, provided by apple), the api is in Obj-C. If you look up the documentation for NSTextView, it is a Obj-C interface with Obj-C methods. There is no getting around that.